# Why is my flutter project is still looking for debug.keystore when I have not generated it?

Tags: android, flutter, android-app-signing

I have my generated and added it to key.properties as :

```
keyAlias=budseeker
storeFile=C:/Users/ASUS/upload-keystore.jks
```

That's the only Keystore present in my system on that path.
That's how I my gradle config looks like:

```
signingConfigs {
   release {
       keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
       keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
       storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
       storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
   }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Yet When I use flutter run it throws me with this exception :

```
    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
> com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\ASUS\.android\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format
```

I have no idea why this happening and why the system is looking for debug.keystore when the setup is not in such a way

Comment: what command you use to run the app?

Comment: I'm using fvm so , I use fvm flutter run

Comment: You should do `fvm flutter run --release`. default is debug when no argument is passed.